# Closable operators on Hilbert modules

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, hilbert-spaces

For $T:{\frak{Dom}}(T) \to H$ a densely defined operator, with $H$ a (separable) Hilbert space, we know that $T$ is closable if its adjoint $T^*$ has dense domain in $H$.

Does this extend to the (left) Hilbert module over a (unital separable) $C^*$-algebra $A$? In more details, for $T$ an densely defined operator on a Hilbert module, will it necessarily be closable if the domain of its adjoint is dense.

Comment: Is this not proved in just the same way as the corresponding result for Hilbert spaces?

Comment: I would guess so, but I wanted to hear from an expert that this is indeed the case :)

Comment: Yes, it is true and proved in just the same way. But the converse fails --- there can be bounded operators which aren't adjointable.

Comment: @Nik: I'm sorry, but I can't see why boundedness or adjointability has to do with closability of unbounded operators. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here

Comment: Bounded operators are closed. If you want a truly unbounded closable operator whose adjoint has non-dense domain, take the direct sum of a bounded operator that's not adjointable and any closed unbounded operator.

Comment: Ok, I see! Thanks a lot.